# How to group records based on a child record in Amazon Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is there any way to categorise an aggregated record in Amazon Quicksight based on the records being aggregated?

I'm trying to build a pivot table an Amazon Quicksight to pull out counts of various records split down by what state the record is in limited to a date range where the record first had activity.

This is all being done in SPICE since the raw data is CSV files in S3. The two CSV files are:

**Student**

- Id: String
- Current State: *One of* `pass` / `fail`
- Department: String

**Test**

- Id: String
- Student Id: String
- DateOfTest: DateTime
- State: *One of* `pass` / `fail`

The pivot table I'm trying to build would have a row for each department and 3 columns:

- **fail** - Count of students in the department where the current state is `fail`
- **pass-never-failed** - Count of students in the department where the current state is `pass` and there are no failed tests for the Student
- **pass-failed-some** - Count of students in the department where the current state is `pass` and there is at least one failed test

To do this I've created a dataset that contains `Student` joined to `Test`. I can then create a Pivot table with:

- Row: `Department`
- Column: `Current State`
- Value: `Count Distinct(Id[Student])`

I thought I'd be able to create a calculated field to give me the three categories and use that in place of `Current State` using the following calculation:

```
ifelse(
    {Current State} = 'pass',

    ifelse(
        countIf({Id[Test]}, {State} = 'fail') = 0,
        'pass-never-failed',
        'pass-failed-some'
    ),

    {Current State}
)
```

But that shows invalid with the following error:

```
Mismatched aggregation. Custom aggregations can’t contain both aggregate "`COUNT`" and non-aggregated fields “COUNT(CASE WHEN "State" = _UTF16'fail' THEN "Id[Test]" ELSE NULL END)”, in any combination.
```

Is there any way to categories the Students based on an aggregation of the Tests in quicksight or do I have to pre-calculate this information in the source data?

I've been able to workaround this for now by defining three separate calculations for the three columns and adding these as values in the quicksight pivot rather than setting a column dimension at all.

**Count Passed Never Failed**

```
distinct_countIf({Id[Student]}, maxOver(
    ifelse({State[Test]} = 'fail' AND {Current State[Student]} = 'pass',
        1, 0)
, [{Id[Student]}], PRE_AGG) = 0)
```

**Count Passed Failed Some**

```
distinct_countIf({Id[Student]}, maxOver(
    ifelse({State[Test]} = 'fail' AND {Current State[Student]} = 'pass',
        1, 0)
, [{Id[Student]}], PRE_AGG) > 0)
```

**Count Failed**

```
distinct_countIf({Id[Student]}, {Current State[Student]} = 'fail')
```

This works, but I'd still like to know if it's possible to build a dimension that I could use for this as it would be more flexible if new states are added without the special handling of pass.

Comment: I can't answer  your question directly, but I have found it easier to set up the data to make it easy to use in Quicksight, vs trying to work around the schema. I'd much rather use python, SQL, Pandas, etc than Quicksight's own unique language.

Comment: Thanks @kielni, that's defiantly my fallback plan. At the moment this is an experimental / exploratory project, so I'm trying to keep as much out of the data loading as possible to maximize flexibility, but it's defiantly an option if I can't do it in quick-sight.

Comment: I think the adding a max/min in the {Current State option} will give you what you want:

   ifelse(
    max({Current State}) = 'pass',

    ifelse(
        countIf({Id[Test]}, {State} = 'fail') = 0,
        'pass-never-failed',
        'pass-failed-some'
    ),

    max({Current State})
)